# Dynamic CSS rebrand and overriding in .Net

Tags: .net, css

I've been tasked with putting a mechanism in place to change the css colours in a .Net site dynamically. The purpose is to ensure that when our internal application sites are built and deployed to our UAT servers that the UI of the site is identifiably different from the live versions without changing the code base.

One option is to go through each site and create a parallel UAT version of the CSS but I would like to have a handler or something in place to replace colour defintions in the CSS based on a key / value pair as our colours are pretty standard across the apps. Ideally it should simply intercept the css request, replace any standard colour code definitions with the required UAT colours and server the CSS out with the replacements. Does this sound like a realistic solution to the problem or can anyone suggest a better approach which doesn't involve managing multiple css definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, I've found something very similiar to what I'm trying to achieve here.

http://pastebin.ca/1205892

Answer (score 0):

Alex (the guy you posted the blog link to) says you need to add the following to the web.config:

If you are using "IIS6 / Visual studio test server":

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.css" type="StyleSheetHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

If you are using IIS7:

It should work, however if it doesn't then you will need to check the mappings like so:

For a website:

```
IIS6 > Website > Home directory
```

For a virtual directory browse to:

```
IIS6 > Virtual folder > Virtual directory (default tab)
```

Click the configuratino button in the application settings area.

Locate the .css extension and check that it is using the aspnet_isapi.dll

If it is not then simply change it so that it is. (You can copy the full URL from any other .NET extension, .aspx for example)

Then everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need something as complicated as HTTP handlers. Just create an .aspx page which outputs CSS. It can be a .aspx and just have your  tag refer to the .aspx page.

If you really want to have your .css pages handled by ASP.NET (I wouldn't because it affects performance), then you want to add an extension mapping like this: http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2008/09/30/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at less:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150138/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030310-1.aspx